# Voice control for Android with limited dictionary

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I would really appreciate little help with voice control for android. I am making voice-controlled chess, but voice recognition is identifying words that I don't want.
**Example: "King to C7" > "Pink 2 See 7"**
So, is there a way how to filter only words that I want to use? Make something like whitelist? Thanks for every response.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible because of the way how speech to text works. Limiting the speech recognition only to some small whitelist would require retraining of the neural network (and that isn't something that an individual can do).